# javascript react-intl-universal: intl.get() value not loaded in the object when the object is imported from another script

Tags: javascript, react-intl-universal

I have this code:

```
  const menuOptions = ['New', 'TASKMANAGEMENT', 'HISTORY']; 

  const menuContents = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < menuOptions.length; i++) {
    const option = menuOptions[i];
    const content = menuOptionsToContent[option];
    console.log('option, content: ');
    console.log(option, content);
    menuContents.push(content);
  }
```

where `menuOptionsToContent` is defined as in:

```
import intl from 'react-intl-universal';


const menuContentForNew = {
  type: 'collapse',
  name: intl.get('dashboard_button_new'),
  key: 'new',
  route: '/new',
  icon: <Icon fontSize="medium">create</Icon>,
  component: <New />,
  noCollapse: true,
};

const menuContentForTaskMangement = {
  type: 'collapse',
  name: intl.get('dashboard_button_task_management'),
  key: 'task-management',
  route: '/task-management',
  icon: <ViewKanbanIcon />,
  component: <Kanban />,
  noCollapse: true,
};

const menuContentForHistory = {
  type: 'collapse',
  name: intl.get('dashboard_button_history'),
  key: 'history',
  icon: <AssignmentIcon />,
  collapse: [
    {
      name: intl.get('dashboard_button_history_received'),
      key: 'received',
      route: '/history/received',
      component: <ReceivedHistory type={ISSUE_LIST_TYPE.TASK_LIST} />,
    },
    {
      name: intl.get('dashboard_button_history_sent'),
      key: 'sent',
      route: '/history/sent',
      component: <SentHistory type={ISSUE_LIST_TYPE.TASK_LIST} />,
    },
  ],
};

export const menuOptionsToContent = {
  'New': menuContentForNew,
  'TASKMANAGEMENT': menuContentForTaskMangement,
  'HISTORY': menuContentForHistory,
};
```

the problem is that when we run

```
    const content = menuOptionsToContent[option];
    console.log('option, content: ');
    console.log(option, content);
```

the `content` is an object like below:

```
{
  type: 'collapse',
  name: ""
  key: 'task-management',
  route: '/task-management',
  icon: <ViewKanbanIcon />,
  component: <Kanban />,
  noCollapse: true,
};
```

It has everything as defined, except that `name` is an empty string `""`, where it should have been an actual name string.

Why is the `intl.get()` value not loaded in the object?

Comment: did you add any locale data? they go in: /src/locales/[locale code eg: en_US].json

Comment: Yes, the locale data is complete. It has something to do with the `intl.get()` function not returning a string value synchronously by the time the object is called.

Comment: thats a good hint. hmmm have you loaded it like in their example?
 https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/tree/master/packages/react-intl-universal/examples/component-example specifically check out IntlResourceLoader.js